# Android Java İmageview with Progress

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, imageview

I also tried `FrameLayout` but doesn't help

[image: imageview like this]

**I have no idea how to do an `ImageView` like this**

Answer (score 1):

You want a sort of `ProgressBar` with an empty shape to fill progressively ?

I think you can use [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources) to do the trick